# Why vrules are not aligned between rows of tabbed alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

How to make `\vrules` aligned against each other in the following example? Why the sample line after `\settabs` does not work as needed?

```
\magnification=\magstep5
\nopagenumbers
\font\ttl=rm-lmtl10
\font\ttb=rm-lmtk10
{\settabs\+ \ttl\ +9 & \ttl\ 9 & \ttb\ CD & \ttb\ E & \ttb\ FGHI & \ttb\ GKLM \cr
\hrule
\+ \vrule\hfill\ttb\ A \hfill\strut\vrule&
   \hfill\ttb\ B \hfill\strut\vrule&
   \ttb\ CD \strut\vrule&
   \ttb\ E \strut\vrule&
   \ttb\ FGHI \strut\vrule&
   \ttb\ GKLM \strut\vrule\cr
\hrule
\+ \vrule\ttl \ +9 \hfill\strut\vrule&
   \ttl\ 9 \hfill\strut\vrule&
   \ttl\ \ 2 \strut\vrule&
   \ttl\ 3 \strut\vrule&
   \hfill\ttl 20 \strut\vrule&
   \hfill\ttl 30 \strut\vrule&\cr
\hrule}
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer -- but this is so complicated. Why not use a tabular?

Comment: @Aubrey Blumsohn This is TeX, not LaTeX. There's no tabular, there are no environments. \halign is what makes a table.

Comment: adding another `&` on the `\settabs` line before the `\cr` will allow the last cell to be filled out, but with the alignment slightly off.  still trying to figure out why the alignment is off anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first column, but FGHI and 20 don't have \hfill at the end. Also, the last column isn't a fixed size \hbox, so you can't make the ends line up easily. Put vrules into the beginning of each field, and use an additional field after the last column just to put a rule there.

Of course, it's better to use \halign.